# Comparing and combining two R sf objects

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial, r-sf

I've created two different types of percentage blue-green coverage at a 250m grid for Helsinki, Finland. One is based on Corine landcover data (i.e. https://land.copernicus.eu/pan-european/corine-land-cover, Finnish data available from Syke https://www.syke.fi/en-US/Open_information/Spatial_datasets/Downloadable_spatial_dataset), the other one is based on Open Street Map (https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/finland.html).

A gpkg version of my prepared datasets can be found [here](https://github.com/demmlerj/blue-green_helsinki).

**I would like to compare and combine the two versions.** (My hypothesis is that OSM is probably better at predicting vegetation greenness and water in inner-city areas). **Is there a spatial command to compare two different `sf` objects?** I.e. something equivalent to `overlay` in the `raster` package.

Ideally, I need to retain the link of the grid ID to link the result later to my socio-economic data.

Introduction to the data

```
# load R packages ####
library(sf)
library(tmap)

# load data for 2014 ####
Corine.bg.2014 <- st_read("COR.2014.gpkg")
OSM.bg.2014 <- st_read("OSM.2014.gpkg")

# plot data ####
tmap_mode("view")

tm_shape(Corine.bg.2014) + 
  tm_polygons("area.pct", palette="Greens") +
  tm_layout(title= "Corine 2014", legend.outside=TRUE)

tm_shape(OSM.bg.2014) + 
  tm_polygons("area.pct", palette="Greens") +
  tm_layout(title= "OSM 2014", legend.outside=TRUE)
```

[image: Corine 2014]
[image: OSM 2014]

So far, the best I could come up with is joining the tables together and subtract one version from the other, e.g.

```
# grab variables to join from OSM data version ####
library(tidyverse)

tmp <- OSM.bg.2014 %>%
       dplyr::select(ID, area.OSM=area.pct) %>%
       as.tibble()

# join OSM version onto Corine table ####
test <- Corine.bg.2014 %>%
          left_join(tmp)

# subtract OSM from Corine blue-green percentage ####
test$diff <- test$area.pct-test$area.OSM

# visualise the result ####
tm_shape(test) + 
  tm_polygons("diff", palette="RdYlGn", 
              style="fisher") +
  tm_layout(title= "difference 2014", legend.outside=TRUE)
```

[image: difference]

Comment: It seems odd that you are using polygons instead of the original raster data. Irrespectively, to be able to answer your question you need to include a *small* example data set, preferably generated with code, but via download if need be.

Comment: a) the original data from Copernicus is in raster format, but the Syke version is in polygons b) So you mean my file is too large? I can crop it.